# Algebraic Long-Division, where the divifing $x$ has a co-efficient

Tags: polynomials

I know how to do algebraic long division when dividing by $(x+a)$ however when a co-efficient is added to the $x$ what do you do? e.g $\frac{x^{3}-4x^{2}+12}{3x-4}$  I recall you having to times by the co-efficient and then dividing by $a$ - or something like so.

I resulted to dividing both the top and bottom of the fraction by the co-efficient to rid $x$ of its co-efficient, and then long-divide traditionally, but this seems like an over-complication and makes lots of room for error as an abundance of fractions are created.

Comment: One way to think about it is to factor out the leading coefficient:  $$ 3x-4 = 3\left(x - \frac{4}{3}\right)$$  Then you only have the problem of dividing by the monic first degree polynomial, $x - 4/3$.

Comment: @James,  in this case, to keep your way,  you just factor out the $3$ in the denominator, put it as $1/3$ factor to the fraction with the monic denom.,  and proceed to divide the remaining fraction

Comment: so y / (3x-4) would turn into y / 3 (x-4/3)? This is the method i mentioned i resorted to, however, this isn't the taught faster way.

Comment: = ( y / 3 ) / (x - 4/3 )

Comment: Do it as you like, and somehow keep track of whatever denominators you have ignored so as not to create fractions. If you take this route, it is then more important to check at the end, after putting the denominators back in.

Comment: Does anyone know of the forgotten method I speak of.

Comment: @James You can make the substitution $u=3x$, multiply the numerator by $3^3=27$ to eliminate the fractions, then divide the final result by 27. Perhaps that is similar to the method you remember. This gives $\frac{1}{27}\cdot\frac{u^3-12u^2+324}{u-4}=\frac{1}{27}\left(u^2-8u-32+\frac{196}{u-4}\right)$ which equals $\frac{1}{27}\left(9x^2-24x-32+\frac{196}{3x-4}\right)=\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{8}{9}x-\frac{32}{27}+\frac{196/27}{3x-4}$. This approach involves minimal use of fractional arithmetic. You can also adapt the method to synthetic division.

Comment: @James I went ahead and posted my comment as a solution since the rules say  that a solution should not be posted as a comment.

Comment: This had nothing whatsoever to do with division-algebras. Please read the tag wiki before using a tag you are unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the substitution $u=3x$, multiply the numerator by $3^3=27$ to eliminate the fractions, then divide the final result by 27. Perhaps that is similar to the method you remember. This gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{27}\cdot\frac{u^3-12u^2+324}{u-4}=\frac{1}{27}\left(u^2-8u-32+\frac{196}{u-4}\right)
\end{equation}
 which equals 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{27}\left(9x^2-24x-32+\frac{196}{3x-4}\right)=\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{8}{9}x-\frac{32}{27}+\frac{196/27}{3x-4}
\end{equation}

This approach involves minimal use of fractional arithmetic. You can also adapt the method to synthetic division.

Comment: Makes sense....